# Wp_admin ajax request returns with response "0"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am new to code, and trying to learn things by doing them.

Currently, I am trying to do something very simple using wordpress. which I am trying to create some posts in wordpress, using some external data.

I can fetch the data using CURL. No problem with that and post it using Wp_insert_post, directly.

But, What I want to do is trigger the wp_insert_post function on click of a button in the admin panel ( I have created this as a plugin and a separate plugin dashboard, where the button Is embedded). I have been messing around with the code, and sending the data to wp-admin-ajax.php work fine, and gives the response code 200. But, the response receiving is "0" . if the data passed through are correct, I presume, the response should be "1" ?

I have the following code at the moment.

`//Button`

```
<form id="formtesting">
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="submit" id="user-submit" value="user-submit">
```

```
//Ajax Call
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userSubmitButton = document.getElementById('user-submit');

  var adminAjaxRequest = function(formData, myaction) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/wpdevelopment/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data: {
        action: myaction,
        data: formData
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (true === response.success) {
          alert('success');
        } else {
          alert(response);
        }
      }
    });
  };

  userSubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = {
      'name': document.getElementById('name').value

    };
    adminAjaxRequest(formData, 'data_submission');
  });
});
```

And here is my test function // to test whether the function initiate properly, i try to send a Json error, So then I can include wp_insert_post details.

```
function data_submission(){


wp_send_json_error( 'I am an error' );}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_data_submission', 'data_submission' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_data_submission', 'data_submission' );
```

Could not locate where the faulty is. Some help would be appriciated

tks

Comment: I  think  problem may  be in your wp-admin-ajax.php file. can you show your  php file code?

Comment: I dont use a seperate or custom built wp-admin-ajax.php, I am making the request directly to the default wordpress admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this is not a standard way to use ajax in wordpress,
use wp_localize_script for embedding the global ajax_url variable,

```
 wp_register_script('plugin-ajaxJs', plugins_url('/js/ajax-call.js', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('plugin-ajaxJs');
    wp_localize_script('plugin-ajaxJs', 'my_ajax_url', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

Now as url in ajax you can add my_ajax_url.ajax_url,
this will send a request to admin-ajax.php.

Now coming to your question
you are returning an wp_json_error so the result is 0,
use this and return whatever data you wants in ajax success,

```
$responce['result'] = 1
wp_send_json( $response );
```

Comment: Thanks Parth, I have used that method to add ajax url, tried and still no luck, error is same, then I used the standard ajax_url, no Luck, then placed the direct url to the ajax-url ( as showing in the console) to make the ajax request. On the console Log, I get code 200,ok. Which I guess the sending data woks,  But, I dont get a success response.  Let me upload a screen capture from the console log

Comment: instead of using wordpress function wp_send_json just try to echo 'string you wants to return' and add die;@Shirantha

Comment: Screen Capture From the console [link](http://i66.tinypic.com/2nlqmp3.jpg)

Comment: it looks okey in screenshot, try to print_r($_POST);exit; in your ajax php function, it it prints the post data, at the end try to echo out data with json_encode($responce);die; @Shirantha

Comment: Please send the screenshot of responce tab instead of header @Shirantha

Comment: You want me to try print_r at the Ajax function or should I print_r in the data_submission function :

Comment: Try that in data_submission function, and send a screenshot of responce tab in console,. @Shirantha

Comment: On the respoinse tab it says "0". Nothing else . here is the screen capture [link](http://tinypic.com/r/3516b14/9)

Comment: If you use print_r($_post) it must return the $_post array, i think its not going in you data_submission function, what is location of your data_submission function? @Shirantha

Comment: Here I have uploaded all files which I have in, [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz3P-mQNJTngZGEyaW5ENmlkckk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: its working just move your data_submission function to main.php file @Shirantha

Comment: Oh, Yes, It works when I move the function to the main file. **Thank You A lot, helping me out here**.  Anyway, Just wondering whether you have an idea of the reason why it was not working whilst it was on the same page, as the button.

Comment: in add_menu_page see you were calling a file, instead of that call a function in which you create your view. it should be wrapped inside the function. @Shirantha

Comment: Understood.. **Thank you**.

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer and add it as the best, it would help me @Shirantha

Answer (score 1):

Use add_action(' wp_ajax_myaction', 'yours_callback_fanc');

wp_ajax_
Remain part is yours action name that is defined into yours ajax call. In yours case it's myaction.

Comment: I tried that as well, But No Luck. <br/>  Anyway, for the discussion, I think I have used the call back function.

Comment: I tried that as well, But No Luck. <br/> Anyway, for the discussion, I think I have used the call back function, at the click event. Is it a wrong way of doing that ?

Comment: In yours function the last line must be wp_die() ;

Comment: Which terminate the ajax request and try to echo the result and in the response of ajax console.log it

Comment: function data_submission(){ echo 'test' ; wp_die();} try this one

Comment: Tried. No Luck , here is the details from console . [link](http://i66.tinypic.com/2nlqmp3.jpg)

Comment: Please upload the response tab output screen shot

Comment: on the response tab, it says "0".  Nothing else.